# From SHA hashing to password

Tags: java, string, hash, passwords

So i have written this code to convert to hash my password and i want now to take the hash and convert it back to string. how is possible to achieve that?

```
package security;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class HashPassword {

    public static String hashPassword(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException 
    {
        MessageDigest sha= MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        sha.update(password.getBytes());
        byte [] b=sha.digest();
        StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
        for(byte b1:b)
        {
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b1 & 0xff).toString());
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       String password="1234";
       System.out.println(password);
       try
       {
       System.out.println(hashPassword(password));
       }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
       {}
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't.  That's the point of hashing.  Why do you think you need the original string, what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other people pointed out, **a hash is not meant to be "converted" back into its original value**. For this exact reason, hashes are used in databases to store passwords. With a hash, that is stored in a database, even if I have access to the database, I can't figure out the password that is stored there.

Now depending on your usage of the hash you can try multiple things:

**1.**
**You just want to make a password unreadable and readable after some time**

 In this case, you could use an encryption and decryption algorithm rather than a hash method. This way, you could get back the original value if you want.

Just as an easy example: https://www.thejavaprogrammer.com/caesar-cipher-java-encryption-decryption/

**NEVER USE ENCRYPTION TO STORE PASSWORDS.**


**2.**
**You want to implement a login/register Service/System where you store the password as a hash.** 
If this is what you want I would suggest the friendly bcrypt: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt
 Today bcrypt is somewhat a standard for hashing passwords and other information. The Java implementation also offers a great way to check if an entered password matches the stored password. So you don't have to crack the hash over the period of days just to check the password.

Java Implementation of bcrypt can be found here: http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/

Answer (score 1):

You can try crack it with [Rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)

Comment: I like the way this answer points to. Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of hashing passwords is to achieve one thing: to make it as hard as possible to to acquire the original password from its hashed version.

You never need that original password anyway. You simply persist the hashed (and salted!) password and whenever you need to authenticate the user again, you ask for his password, hash that, and check if that matches the persisted hashed password you stored earlier on.

So: whilst it is sometimes possible to acquire the password from its hash, that is simply something you don't care about (unless you are a cryptographer who wants to assess the quality of the hashing implementation).